# Can't access private variables from friend function?

Tags: c++

For some reason I can't seem to access the private variables from a friend function. Here is the function in question:

```
IntArray operator+(const IntArray& in1){
    int secArray[SIZE];
    IntArray a;
        for (int i = low(); i <= compare(high(), in1.high()); i++){
            a.iArray[i] = iArray[i] + in1.iArray[i];              // Combine elements of array   to new array
        }
        return a(iArray);
    }
    else{
        cout << "Error, second array larger than first. Exiting";   // If second array size is larger than first
        exit(0);
    }
}
```

and here is my header file:

```
#ifndef _INTARRAY_H
#define _INTARRAY_H
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

const int SIZE = 100;

class IntArray{
private:
    int iArray[SIZE];
    int arrLower, arrUpper;
    int size;
    string name;

public:
    IntArray();
    IntArray(int range);
    IntArray(int lower, int upper);
    IntArray(const IntArray& input);
    int high() const;
    int low() const;
    int compare(int in1, int in2) const;
    int operator==(const IntArray& in);
    int operator!=(const IntArray& in);
    void setName(string input);
    IntArray& operator=(const IntArray& in);
    int& operator[] (int size)             {  return iArray[size];  }
    IntArray& operator+=( const IntArray& );
    friend IntArray operator+( const IntArray in1 );
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const IntArray& i);



};



#endif
```

Secondly, is that the correct way of returning an array after summing each member?

Comment: What would `iArray` be inside the friend function `operator+`?

Comment: This is not a minimal testcase.

Answer (score 1):

Your friend declaration is missing the reference declarator:

```
friend IntArray operator+( const IntArray in1 );
```

so it is a different function.  It must match the function exactly:

```
       IntArray operator+(const IntArray& in1)
```

(Also you are silently passing the array by value (SLOW!))

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that you are declaring this friend function:

```
friend IntArray operator+( const IntArray in1 );
```

but you are defining this function:

```
IntArray operator+(const IntArray& in1){
//                               ^
```

Another problem is that inside the function you are using an `iArray` object that is not defined. You probably meant for that function to accept two `IntArray`s instead of one.

---

Turns out you don't need that whole class at all. Most of its functionality can be achieved using the standard library.

1. `std::array<int, SIZE>` instead of `IntArray`
2. `std::max_element` instead of the `high` function
3. `std::min_element` instead of the `low` function
4. `std::equal` instead of `operator==` and `operator!=`

And so on. You probably want to take a look at `std::merge` or `std::copy` for that `operator+`.